GitHub CLI or API Programmatically add Target Repos to org Repo Ruleset
For an ORG, I have a default ruleset we are evaluating. I'm trying to add, programmatically, "select repositories" to the Target repositories area (see screenshot).

I can view the settings for my org ruleset with:
gh ruleset view ID --org <myorg>

however, see no way to create or update a repo ruleset via CLI. I've run into walls with Octokit and the API doesn't want to play either...
Does anyone have experience doing this?
